# How to debug kafka in kubernetes (minikube) using telepresence

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube, telepresence

I have Kafka running inside Minikube. Kafka works fine, but I want to use it in my Java app that is located on my local machine (not minikube). I know that it's possible to proxy requests from a local machine to a kubernetes cluster using Telepresence.

I'm trying to run `telepresence intercept -n kafka kafka-service 9092:9092`, but the error occurs `telepresence: error: workload "kafka-service.kafka" not found`.
I know the actual addresses of kafka brokers look like `kafka-0.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092`. However, I don't understand how to make it work.

kafka.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kafka
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kafka-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: '/mnt/data'
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kafka-pv-claim
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9092
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    app: kafka
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-service
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: kafka-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kafka-pv-claim
      containers:
        - name: kafka-container
          image: evmusonov/kafka-kraft
          resources:
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
            - containerPort: 9093
          env:
            - name: REPLICAS
              value: '3'
            - name: SERVICE
              value: kafka-service
            - name: NAMESPACE
              value: kafka
            - name: SHARE_DIR
              value: /mnt/kafka
          volumeMounts:
            - name: kafka-storage
              mountPath: /mnt/kafka
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11

ENV KAFKA_VERSION=3.2.0
ENV SCALA_VERSION=2.13
ENV KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${KAFKA_HOME}/bin

LABEL name="kafka" version=${KAFKA_VERSION}

RUN wget -O /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz \
 && tar xfz /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt \
 && rm /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz \
 && ln -s /opt/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION} ${KAFKA_HOME} \
 && rm -rf /tmp/kafka_${SCALA_VERSION}-${KAFKA_VERSION}.tgz

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And the `entrypoint.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NODE_ID=${HOSTNAME:6}
LISTENERS="PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093"
ADVERTISED_LISTENERS="PLAINTEXT://kafka-$NODE_ID.$SERVICE.$NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local:9092"

CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=""
for i in $( seq 0 $REPLICAS); do
    if [[ $i != $REPLICAS ]]; then
        CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS="$CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS$i@kafka-$i.$SERVICE.$NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local:9093,"
    else
        CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=${CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS::-1}
    fi
done

mkdir -p $SHARE_DIR/$NODE_ID

if [[ ! -f "$SHARE_DIR/cluster_id" && "$NODE_ID" = "0" ]]; then
    CLUSTER_ID=$(kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)
    echo $CLUSTER_ID > $SHARE_DIR/cluster_id
else
    CLUSTER_ID=$(cat $SHARE_DIR/cluster_id)
fi

sed -e "s+^node.id=.*+node.id=$NODE_ID+" \
-e "s+^controller.quorum.voters=.*+controller.quorum.voters=$CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS+" \
-e "s+^listeners=.*+listeners=$LISTENERS+" \
-e "s+^advertised.listeners=.*+advertised.listeners=$ADVERTISED_LISTENERS+" \
-e "s+^log.dirs=.*+log.dirs=$SHARE_DIR/$NODE_ID+" \
/opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties > server.properties.updated \
&& mv server.properties.updated /opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties

kafka-storage.sh format -t $CLUSTER_ID -c /opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties

exec kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties
```

Spring-boot application.properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = kafka-0.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-1.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-2.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers = kafka-0.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-1.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-2.kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = "custom"
```

Comment: You don't need Telepresence. Have you read documentation from Strimzi operator about how it can offer external client access using Ingress or ClusterIp services?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No, I have not. Is that a right way to open an external access to a service for testing purposes though?

Comment: My main point is that 1) Using an operator and/or pre-existing Helm Charts is likely safer than making your own resource definitions 2) You don't need any extra networking services such as Telepresence to access Kafka outside the cluster, no. Besides that, Telepresence is for running a _Kafka image_ on your local machine, not for running Java client to communicate with Kafka inside of the cluster. And if you intercepted Kafka requests locally, it probably wouldn't be able to communicate with the rest of the brokers in the cluster without having the advertised listeners exposed correctly.